# Python merging two dataframes and group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I need to derive the above expected df3 by merging df & df1 and below statistics is required :

Pointed to be noted while merging : If value is not there in "Desc1" it should pick the value from "Desc2"

1. Each Card name and cross tab each category and percentage of amount spent on each category. ( i.e ) Sum of amount of each category/total sum of amount for each card name
2. Top 2 categories of each Card name based on the Amount spent ( All this this should be grouped by Card )
   Can help pls ? Also suggest what more statistics can we infer from df3 ?

I have 2 DFs as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Customer_no": ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '6', '7','8','9','10'],
      "Card_no": ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777','888','999','000'],
      "Card_name":['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCC','AAA','DDD','EEE','BBB','CCC','CCC'],
      "Group_code":['123','123','456','678','123','434','678','365','678','987'],
      "Amount":['100','240','450','212','432','123','543','567','232','453']})
```

Second DF :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Group_code": ['123', '123','456', '678','678', '434', '987','421'],
                 "Desc1": ['Electrical', 'Electrical','Hardware', 'House', 'House', 'Car','','Toy'],
                "Desc2":['Electricals111','Electricals123','Hardware112','House232','House112',
                        'Car','Bike','Toy']})
```

Expected DF :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Customer_no": ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '6', '7','8','9','10'],
      "Card_no": ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777','888','999','000'],
      "Card_name":['AAA','AAA','BBB','CCC','AAA','DDD','EEE','BBB','CCC','CCC'],
      "Group_code":['123','123','456','678','123','434','678','365','678','987'],
      "Amount":['100','240','450','212','432','123','543','567','232','453'],
      "Category" :['Electrical','Electrical','Hardware','House','Electrical','Car','House','','House','Bike']})
```

Comment: Just forgot to add a point : In case in df1 we should select from Desc2 only if Desc1 is Null while merging

Comment: If there is no value in Desc1 then we should select the value from Desc2 and merge it with the Dataframe - df in "Category" column

Comment: Hello @Sheriff, you should rather edit your question to have the whole information in the same place instead of commenting additional material. For your question you should take a look at [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: @Sheriff you can edit your original post rather than adding comments underneath here.  It would be very useful if, as well as showing the structure of the individual dataframes and the resultant one, you could include a sample of the output statistics/tables you seek.  You may find [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a useful reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can first left join, then merge the columns using `where`

```
df3 = df.merge(df1, how='left')  # do the join
df3 = df3.rename(columns={"Desc1": "Category"})
df3 = df3.replace("", np.nan)  # replace empty strings
# if Category is NaN, replace with value from Desc2
df3["Category"] = df3["Category"].where(~df3["Category"].isna(), df3["Desc2"])  
df3 = df3.drop("Desc2", axis=1).drop_duplicates()  # drop Desc2

   Customer_no Card_no Card_name Group_code Amount    Category
0            1     111       AAA        123    100  Electrical
2            1     222       AAA        123    240  Electrical
4            1     333       BBB        456    450    Hardware
5            2     444       CCC        678    212       House
7            2     555       AAA        123    432  Electrical
9            6     666       DDD        434    123         Car
10           7     777       EEE        678    543       House
12           8     888       BBB        365    567         NaN
13           9     999       CCC        678    232       House
15          10     000       CCC        987    453        Bike
```

Comment: Thanks, i may require to select values from Desc2 if there is no value in Desc1. How do i do it ?

Comment: You should edit that into your question, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Sheriff I've updated my comment, that should do the trick. If the value in Desc1/Category is NaN, it will be replaced with the value from Desc2.

Comment: Thanks., Merging is also fine. But its not picking the value from "Desc2" if the value in "Desc1" is null. Pls help

Comment: @Sheriff can you provide an example? My answer does choose the value from Desc2 if Desc1 is `NaN`. However, in your dataframe, there are no rows where Desc1 is `NaN` and Desc2 is filled, so the situation you are trying to recreate never happens. Maybe edit your question with another sample DataFrame that reflects the issue?

Comment: its really nice to seek ur help.

Comment: i have updated the code with Null in df1 and ran ur code to create df3. Unfortunately its nots working

Comment: @Sheriff Your "null" value is the empty string and not `NaN`, which is not working. If you want to replace empty strings with `NaN`s so that you can fill them from the second column, you can use `.replace("",np.nan)`. I've updated my comment above.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will go through it. You were really nice.

Comment: @Sheriff okay, good luck! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
df4 = pd.merge(df, df1[['Desc1','Group_code']].drop_duplicates(), how='left', on=['Group_code'])
df4=df4[['Amount','Card_name','Card_no','Desc1','Customer_no','Group_code']] # Reordering of column sequence
df4=df4.rename(columns={'Desc1':'Category'})
df4=df4.fillna({'Category':''})
df4
  Amount Card_name Card_no    Category Customer_no Group_code
0    100       AAA     111  Electrical           1        123
1    240       AAA     222  Electrical           1        123
2    450       BBB     333    Hardware           1        456
3    212       CCC     444       House           2        678
4    432       AAA     555  Electrical           2        123
5    123       DDD     666         Car           6        434
6    543       EEE     777       House           7        678
7    567       BBB     888                       8        365
8    232       CCC     999       House           9        678
9    453       CCC     000        Bike          10        987
```